# Why is my program getting rid of more_than_1 digit input?

Tags: c++, list

I am learning doubly linked lists in class right now and I was assigned to write a program that takes input from a file, create a doubly linked list, sort it and output to screen. I am observing odd behavior and I cannot figure out why.

In the data file, when I input a number more than 1 digit long, it is making it dissapear. However, if all my inputs are single digit, the program works fine and sorts as it should. I realize that their may be other errors, I will figure those out later. I just need to know why it is removing the double digit input.

My program works when my integer.dat file looks like "6 4 2 8 4 9 0 4". But when my integer.dat file has a number larger then 9, it "wheets it out".

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Node1
{
    int item = 9;
    Node1 * prev = NULL;
    Node1 * next = NULL;
};

Node1 * findlastnode (Node1 *base)
{
    while (base->next != NULL)
    {
        base = base->next;
    }
    return base;
}

Node1 * findFirstNode(Node1 * base)
{
    Node1 * nodefirst = base;

    while (nodefirst->prev != NULL)
    {
        nodefirst = nodefirst->prev;
    }
    return nodefirst;
}

int countNodes(Node1 * base)
{
    int counter = 0;
    Node1 * first = findFirstNode(base);

    while (first->next != NULL)
    {
        counter++;
        first = first->next;
    }
    return counter;
}

void swapItem(Node1 * a1, Node1 * a2)
{
    int temp;
    temp = a1->item;
    a1->item = a2->item;
    a2->item = temp;
}

Node1 * deleteLastNode(Node1 * a1)
{
    a1 = a1->prev;
    Node1 * temp = a1->next;
    delete temp;
    return a1;
}

void print(Node1 * head)
{
    Node1 * tempo = head;

    while (tempo->next != NULL)
    {
        cout << tempo->item << " ";
        tempo = tempo->next;
    }
}

void printDescending(Node1 * head)
{
    Node1 * end = findlastnode(head);

    while (end->prev != NULL)
    {
        cout << end->item << " ";
        end = end->prev;
    }
}

void printEvenAscending(Node1 * head)
{
    Node1 * tempo = head;

    while (tempo->next != NULL)
    {
        if (tempo->item % 2 == 0)
        {
            cout << tempo->item << " ";
            tempo = tempo->next;
        }

    }
}

void printEvenDescending(Node1 * head)
{
    Node1 * end = findlastnode(head);

    while (end->prev != NULL)
    {
        if (end->item % 2 == 0)
        {
        cout << end->next << " ";
        end = end->prev;
        }
    }
}

Node1 * createList(ifstream & intfile)
{
    Node1 * headNode = new Node1;
    Node1 * tempNode = new Node1;

    headNode->next = tempNode;
    tempNode->prev = headNode;

    intfile >> headNode->item;


    int counter = 1;
    while (!intfile.eof())
    {
        intfile >> tempNode->item;

        Node1 * newNode = new Node1;

        tempNode->next = newNode;

        newNode->prev = tempNode;

        tempNode = newNode;

        counter++;

    }
    tempNode->next = NULL;

    return headNode;
}

void sortMyList(Node1 * inputList)
{
    bool isSorted = false;
    Node1 * headNode = inputList;

    Node1 * iterator = headNode;


    while (!isSorted)
    {
        if (iterator->next == NULL) break;

        if ( (iterator->item > iterator->next->item) && !isSorted)
        {

            if (iterator->next != NULL)
            { 
                swapItem(iterator, iterator->next);
            }
            iterator = headNode;
        }

        if ( iterator->next->item >= iterator->item ) 
        {
            iterator = iterator->next;
        }
    }
}

void addToList(Node1 * head, int xyz)
{
    Node1 * lastNode = findlastnode(head);

    Node1 * newNode = new Node1;
    lastNode->next = newNode;
    newNode->prev = lastNode;
    newNode->item = xyz;

    cout << "New List will sort." << endl;

    sortMyList(head);
}

void removeFromList(Node1 * head,int xyz1)
{
    Node1 * someNode = head;
    Node1 * tempNode;
    Node1 * tempNode1;

    bool notremoved = true;

    while (notremoved)
    {
        if (someNode->item == xyz1)
        {
            //Case if first node
            if (someNode->prev == NULL)
            {
                someNode = someNode->next;
                delete someNode->prev;
                someNode->prev = NULL;
                notremoved = false;
            }


            //case if the last node
            if (someNode->next == NULL)
            {
                someNode = someNode->prev;
                delete someNode->next;
                someNode->next = NULL;
                notremoved = false;
            }

            //Case if some node in the middle
            if (someNode->next != NULL && someNode->prev != NULL)
            {
                tempNode = someNode->prev;
                tempNode1 = tempNode;
                tempNode->next = someNode->next;

                tempNode = someNode->next;
                tempNode->prev = tempNode1;
                delete someNode;

                notremoved = false;
            }

            someNode = someNode->next;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Lab 6" << endl << endl;

    ifstream intfile;
    string inputfilename1;

    cout << "Would you like to use the built-in integer.dat? (y/n)" << endl;
    char answer;
    cin >> answer;
    if (answer == 'n')
    {
        cout << endl << "Ok. Where is integer.dat? " << endl;
        cin >> inputfilename1;
        cout << endl;
        intfile.open(inputfilename1.c_str());
    }
    else if (answer == 'y')
    {
        intfile.open("integer.dat");
    }



    if (!intfile)
    {   cout << "Error: File cannot be opened" << endl << "Please input a valid file location: ";
        string inputfilename;
        cin >> inputfilename;
        intfile.open(inputfilename.c_str()); }

    if (intfile.peek() == std::ifstream::traits_type::eof())
    {   cout << "Error: Empty File." << endl << "Please input file name: ";
        string inputfilename1;
        cin >> inputfilename1;
        intfile.open(inputfilename1.c_str()); }


    Node1 * myList = createList(intfile);

    cout << "List before sort : " << endl;
    print(myList);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "List after sort : " << endl;
    sortMyList(myList);
    print(myList);

    bool runagain = true;
    while (runagain)
    {
        cout << endl << "What would you like to do ? " << endl << endl;
        cout << "A) Print out sorted list Ascending" << endl;
        cout << "B) Print out sorted list Descending" << endl;
        cout << "C) Print out EVEN sorted list Ascending" << endl;
        cout << "D) Print out EVEN sorted list Descending" << endl;
        cout << "E) Add Integer to list" << endl;
        cout << "F) Remove Integer from list" << endl;
        cout << "Type a letter and press enter ( eg. 'c' ): ";
        cin >> answer;

        if (answer == 'A' || answer == 'a')
        {
            cout << "List in Ascending order : " << endl;
            print(myList);
            cout << endl << "Would you like to run the program again? (y/n)" << endl;
            cin >> answer;
            if (answer == 'n') runagain = false;

        }

        if (answer == 'B' || answer == 'b')
        {
            cout << "List in Descending order : " << endl;
            printDescending(myList);
            cout << endl << "Would you like to run the program again? (y/n)" << endl;
            cin >> answer;
            if (answer == 'n') runagain = false;
        }

        if (answer == 'C' || answer == 'c')
        {
            cout << "List of EVEN Ascending: " << endl;
            printEvenAscending(myList);
            cout << endl << "Would you like to run the program again? (y/n)" << endl;
            cin >> answer;
            if (answer == 'n') runagain = false;
        }

        if (answer == 'd' || answer == 'D')
        {
            cout << "List of Even Descending: " << endl;
            printEvenDescending(myList);
            cout << endl << "Would you like to run the program again? (y/n)" << endl;
            cin >> answer;
            if (answer == 'n') runagain = false;
        }

        if (answer == 'e' || answer == 'E')
        {
            cout << "What integer would you like to add?" << endl;
            int xyz;
            cin >> xyz;
            addToList(myList, xyz);
            print(myList);
            cout << endl << "Would you like to run the program again? (y/n)" << endl;
            cin >> answer;
            if (answer == 'n') runagain = false;
        }

        if (answer == 'f' || answer == 'F')
        {
            cout << "What integer would you like removed?" << endl;
            int xyz1;
            cin >> xyz1;
            removeFromList(myList, xyz1);
            print(myList);
            cout << endl << "Would you like to run the program again? (y/n)" << endl;
            cin >> answer;
            if (answer == 'n') runagain = false;
        }
    }




    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

edit: here is the updated code! thanks for everyones help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Node1
{
    int item;
    Node1 * prev ;
    Node1 * next ;
};

Node1 * findTail (Node1 * node)
{
    Node1 * base = node;
    while (base->next != NULL)
    {
        base = base->next;
    }
    return base;
}

Node1 * findFirstNode(Node1 * base)
{
    Node1 * nodefirst = base;

    while (nodefirst->prev != NULL)
    {
        nodefirst = nodefirst->prev;
    }
    return nodefirst;
}

int countNodes(Node1 * base)
{
    int counter = 0;
    Node1 * first = findFirstNode(base);

    while (first->next != NULL)
    {
        counter++;
        first = first->next;
    }
    return counter;
}

void swapItem(Node1 * a1, Node1 * a2)
{
    int temp;
    temp = a1->item;
    a1->item = a2->item;
    a2->item = temp;
}

Node1 * deleteLastNode(Node1 * a1)
{
    a1 = a1->prev;
    Node1 * temp = a1->next;
    delete temp;
    return a1;
}

void print(Node1 * head)
{
    Node1 * tempo = head;

    //We check to see if tempo isnt null, not temp->next because wed be checking tempo->next twice
    while (tempo != NULL)
    {
        cout << tempo->item << " ";
        tempo = tempo->next;
    } 
}

//CORRECT
void printDescending(Node1 * head)
{
    Node1 * end = findTail(head);
    cout << end->item << " ";
    while (end->prev != NULL)
    {
        end = end->prev;
        cout << end->item << " ";

    }

}
//correct
void printEvenAscending(Node1 * node)
{
    Node1 * top = node;

    if (top->item % 2 == 0)
    {
        cout << top->item << " ";
    }

    while (top->next != NULL)
    {
        top = top->next;

        if (top->item % 2 == 0)
        {
            cout << top->item << " ";
        }

    }
}
//CORRECT
void printEvenDescending(Node1 * node)
{
    Node1 * bottom = findTail(node);

    if (bottom->item % 2 == 0)
    {
        cout << bottom->item << " ";
    }

    while (bottom->prev != NULL)
    {
        bottom = bottom->prev;

        if (bottom->item % 2 == 0)
        {
        cout << bottom->item << " ";
        }
    }
}
//CORRECT
Node1 * createList(ifstream & intfile)
{
    Node1 * head;
    Node1 * tail;
    Node1 * temp;

    temp = new Node1;
    intfile >> temp->item;
    temp->prev = NULL;
    head = temp;
    tail = temp;

    while (intfile.peek() != std::ifstream::traits_type::eof()) //if theres data, do this run
    {
        temp = new Node1;
        intfile >> temp->item;
        temp->prev = tail;
        tail->next = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }
    tail->next = NULL;

    return head;

}
//CORRECT
void sortMyList(Node1 * inputList)
{
    bool isSorted = false;
    Node1 * headNode = inputList;

    Node1 * iterator = headNode;


    while (!isSorted)
    {
        // at the beginning of each iteration we suppose the list is already sorted
        isSorted = true;
        iterator = headNode;
        // till the end of list
        while (iterator->next != NULL)
        {
            if (iterator->next->next != NULL)
            {
                if ((iterator->item > iterator->next->item))
                {
                    // change elements
                    swapItem(iterator, iterator->next);
                    // if change was, so sorting not completed
                    isSorted = false;
                }
            }
            // go to next item
            iterator = iterator->next;
        }
    }
}

Node1 * addToList(Node1 * head, int xyz)
{

    Node1 * node = head;
    Node1 * newNode = new Node1;

    newNode->item = xyz;
    node->prev = newNode;
    newNode->next = node;
    newNode->prev = NULL;

    return newNode;

}

void removeFromList(Node1 * head,int xyz1)
{

    Node1 * node = head;
    Node1 * nodebefore;
    Node1 * nodeafter;

    bool notfound = true;
    while (notfound)
    {
        node = node->next;
        if (node->item == xyz1)
        {
            notfound = false;
        }
    }

    nodebefore = node->prev;
    nodeafter = node->next;
    delete node;
    nodebefore->next = nodeafter;
    nodeafter->prev = nodebefore;

}

int main()
{
    cout << "Lab 6" << endl << endl;

    ifstream intfile;
    string inputfilename1;

    cout << "Would you like to use the built-in integer.dat? (y/n)" << endl;
    char answer;
    cin >> answer;
    if (answer == 'n')
    {
        cout << endl << "Ok. Where is integer.dat? " << endl;
        cin >> inputfilename1;
        cout << endl;
        intfile.open(inputfilename1.c_str());
    }
    else if (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')
    {
        intfile.open("integer.dat");
    }



    if (!intfile)
    {   cout << "Error: File cannot be opened" << endl << "Please input a valid file location: ";
        string inputfilename;
        cin >> inputfilename;
        intfile.open(inputfilename.c_str()); }

    if (intfile.peek() == std::ifstream::traits_type::eof())
    {   cout << "Error: Empty File." << endl << "Please input file name: ";
        string inputfilename1;
        cin >> inputfilename1;
        intfile.open(inputfilename1.c_str()); }

    Node1 * myList = createList(intfile);

    cout << "List before sort : " << endl;
    print(myList);
    cout << endl;
    /*
    cout << "List after sort : " << endl;
    sortMyList(myList);
    print(myList);
    */
    bool runagain = true;
    while (runagain)
    {
        cout << endl << "What would you like to do ? " << endl << endl;
        cout << "A) Print out sorted list Ascending" << endl;
        cout << "B) Print out sorted list Descending" << endl;
        cout << "C) Print out EVEN sorted list Ascending" << endl;
        cout << "D) Print out EVEN sorted list Descending" << endl;
        cout << "E) Add Integer to list" << endl;
        cout << "F) Remove Integer from list" << endl;
        cout << "Type a letter and press enter ( eg. 'c' ): ";
        cin >> answer;

        if (answer == 'A' || answer == 'a')
        {
            cout << "List in Ascending order : " << endl;
            sortMyList(myList);
            print(myList);
            cout << endl << endl  << "Would you like to run the program again? (y/n)" << endl;
            cin >> answer;
            if (answer == 'n') runagain = false;

        }

        if (answer == 'B' || answer == 'b')
        {
            cout << "List in Descending order : " << endl;
            sortMyList(myList);
            printDescending(myList);
            cout << endl << "Would you like to run the program again? (y/n)" << endl;
            cin >> answer;
            if (answer == 'n') runagain = false;
        }

        if (answer == 'C' || answer == 'c')
        {
            cout << "List of EVEN Ascending: " << endl;
            sortMyList(myList);
            printEvenAscending(myList);
            cout << endl << "Would you like to run the program again? (y/n)" << endl;
            cin >> answer;
            if (answer == 'n') runagain = false;
        }

        if (answer == 'd' || answer == 'D')
        {
            cout << "List of Even Descending: " << endl;
            sortMyList(myList);
            printEvenDescending(myList);
            cout << endl << "Would you like to run the program again? (y/n)" << endl;
            cin >> answer;
            if (answer == 'n') runagain = false;
        }

        if (answer == 'e' || answer == 'E')
        {
            cout << "What integer would you like to add?" << endl;
            int xyz;
            cin >> xyz;
            Node1 * newHead = addToList(myList, xyz);
            myList = newHead;
            print(myList);
            cout << endl << "Would you like to run the program again? (y/n)" << endl;
            cin >> answer;
            if (answer == 'n') runagain = false;
        }

        if (answer == 'f' || answer == 'F')
        {
            cout << "Currently does not support removal of first or last element." << endl;
            cout << "What integer would you like removed?" << endl;
            int xyz1;
            cin >> xyz1;
            removeFromList(myList, xyz1);
            print(myList);
            cout << endl << "Would you like to run the program again? (y/n)" << endl;
            cin >> answer;
            if (answer == 'n') runagain = false;
        }
    }




    system("pause");
    return 0;
}<code>
```

Comment: What does "wheets it out" mean?

Comment: When I ask it to output the sorted linked list, the data input that has more than 1 digit is gone. If you would like, run the program and it will display the linked list without the double digit number.

Comment: What the variable `isSorted` in `sortMyList` is used for? I do not see where you change its value

Comment: `while (!intfile.eof())` is broken logic - dozens of SO questions explaining why and what to do instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the way you create your list from the input. It always adds one more node than you want.

On the other hand your print() function stops printing one node too early (it only prints nodes that have a successor).

Since your default value for a new Node is 9, this will always be the largest value if you only have single digit numbers, so you don't see the problem there.

Answer (score 0):

Change declaration of structure to

```cpp
struct Node1
{
    int item;
    Node1 * prev;
    Node1 * next;
};
```

And try the following sort function:

```cpp
void sortMyList(Node1 * inputList)
{
    bool isSorted = false;
    Node1 * headNode = inputList;
    Node1 * iterator = headNode;

    while (!isSorted)
    {
        // at the beginning of each iteration we suppose the list is already sorted
        isSorted = true;
        iterator = headNode;
        // till the end of list
        while (iterator->next != NULL)
        {
            if( iterator->next->next != NULL )
            {
                if ( (iterator->item > iterator->next->item) )
                {
                    // change elements
                    swapItem(iterator, iterator->next);
                    // if change was, so sorting not completed
                    isSorted = false;
                }
            }
            // go to next item
            iterator = iterator->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That will break all sorts of things... much of the code (e.g. `CreateList`) depends on newly created `Node`'s having the member variable value initialisation you've removed.

Comment: You are welcome! And for future try to write comments for your code, especially when you code is more than 10 lines :-)